# Link FFmpeg with CMake on Windows

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, cmake, linker, mingw

I'm new to CMake and I've been scratching my heads for a couple of days on this. I downloaded the FFmpeg source code and built it without issues. I got a lib folder and an include folder which I placed in my project structure:

```
project
   \--- build
   \--- dep
      \---ffmpeg
         \--- include
         \--- lib
   main.cpp
   CMakeLists.txt
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(VidShare)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(VidShare main.cpp)
include_directories(dep/ffmpeg/include)
target_link_libraries(VidShare
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/ffmpeg/lib/libavformat.a
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.a)
```

and here is my main.cpp:

```
extern "C" {
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    AVFormatContext *pFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
    return 0;
}
```

As soon as I add this line of code: `AVFormatContext *pFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();` I get this error when building in CLion:

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable VidShare.exe
CMakeFiles\VidShare.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
D:/Users/dalla/Documents/Coding Projects/C++/VidShare/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `avformat_alloc_context'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\VidShare.dir\build.make:107: VidShare.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: CMakeFiles/VidShare.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:101: CMakeFiles/VidShare.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:136: VidShare] Error 2
```

I'm guessing this is a linker error and that I don't know how to link it properly (might be something stupid I am missing) as avformat_alloc_context() seems to be in the header file. Anyways, I'm quite desperate and some help would be appreciated.

I am using:

- MinGW
- CLion
- Windows 10
- CMake

Comment: Your CMake rules do not follow the best practices. You should be letting CMake figure out the extensions of the libraries instead of providing them yourself. Moreover, you should be using `target_link_directory` to provide the directory for CMake to search the libraries instead of providing the full paths repeatedly in `target_link_library`.

Comment: Can you place this repository somewhere accessible, so I can try building it myself?

Comment: @Nahiyan I tried modifying my CMakeLists.txt by removing the extensions and using `target_link_directory` and now I get an error saying somethin about `skipping incompatible libavformat.a when searching for -lavformat`. I have to admit I am not sure how to use target_link_directory. Anyways, I have uploaded a zip file of the original project in dropbox, here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7oqho0gsnw66lex/AADb7XWynT1JWtM_LsDRQB99a?dl=0. Thank you for your time

Comment: I posted my answer. Mind sharing how you obtained the binaries?

Comment: I also compiled the FFmpeg libraries from the source, replacing the libraries that you provided, which fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully managed to build this project using `libavcodec` and `libavformat` on Ubuntu 20.04. I simply ran `sudo apt install libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev` to install the development libraries of `avformat` and `avcodec`. As for finding the libraries (which are in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` in my case), I used the [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) function of CMake.

This is how your CMake file may look like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(VidShare)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(VidShare main.cpp)
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/ffmpeg/include)
find_library(AVFORMAT_LIB avformat)
find_library(AVCODEC_LIB avcodec)
target_link_libraries(VidShare ${AVFORMAT_LIB} ${AVCODEC_LIB})
```

I believe the libraries in your `dep/ffmpeg/lib` directory couldn't be loaded successfully by the linker for some reason. I used GNU nm to list the symbols but couldn't find anything unexpected or missing. Nevertheless, it's always best practice to use official pre-compiled binaries whenever possible.

Comment: I would have used pre-compiled binaries but I did not know how to find them as I am on windows. However I found this tool called vcpkg today and installed the .lib files from there and I am now trying to set everything up with vcpkg. I figured the libraries I built myself were probably the problem...

Comment: I see. Can you try using MSVC to compile them instead of MinGW?

Comment: with the static download I get undefined references. I downloaded the dynamic build to try. The project compiles fine but when I run the executable I get this exit code: `-1073741515 (0xC0000135)` which means there are some missing .dll I think... This happens on both MSVC and MinGW

Comment: I have added the .dll files in my system Path variable and it seems to be working fine for now. However I would rather use static linking... Any idea how I could achieve that? Right now dynamic works for both MinGW and MSVC. Thanks a LOT for the help by the way:)

Comment: As for the dynamically linked version, can you please use a dependency walker and see what it reports? It should be able to help you identify the missing DLL[s]. This may help us resolve the issue with static linking.

Comment: as I said dynamic linking works fine I just had to put the path to the DLLs in my system path variable. I can code just fine. Maybe the static build from vcpkg is not complete or something is wrong with my cmake file. Since I successfully linked it I guess I could post an answer although it is not statically linked.